# passing an id to Create of other model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In this actionLink I get the id from Cliente.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pets", "Create", "Pets", new {id = Model.ClientId}, null)
```

Than i send this id to a view bag in PetController

```
  public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ClienteId", "Nome");
        return View();
    }
```

But when a run the code, the dropdown show more than one Client.

[As you can see in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8Qp.png)

how can i show only de client who have the id that a i get in the actionlink ?

Thank's.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @StephenMuecke \**whispers\** *I think he wants us to make it for him.*

Comment: @StephenMuecke i need to add a method in @Html.ActionLink("Pets", "Create", "Pets") to get the clienteId.  and the view bag recive the clienteId that we get in the actionlink.

Comment: Still not clear, but if you wanting to pass the value of `ClienteId` to the `Create` method` -  change the link to `@Html.ActionLink("Pets", "Create", "Pets", new { id = Model.ClienteId }, null )` and the controller method to `Create(int id)`

Comment: @Phiter I just need an example for help me do that. and I edited the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry english is not my frist language. But the @.ActionLink is in Models.Cliente, and the view bag is in controller from Models.Pet , if a add Create( id) the view bag will only select the Id, that was get in  in the actionLink ?

Answer (score 0):

At Html

```
@Html.ActionLink("Pets", "Create", "Pets", new {id = Model.ClientId}, null)
```

At PetController

```
  public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ClienteId", "Nome");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thank's but still no working, i've edited the question and added a image for you .

Comment: But the Action recives the id correctly ? db.Clientes what contains?